# ハードウェアの学習のためのWEBサイトを教えていただけませんか

Tags: ハードウェア

ソフトウェア開発、プログラミング初心者です。

ソフトウェアについての学習をしているのですが、コンピュータをハードウェアから理解したいと非常に強く思うようになりました。

ハードウェアの構成要素についてWEBで調べてみても、入力装置、出力装置、記憶装置、演算装置、制御装置が持つ役割とそれぞれの関連についての概要を説明したWEBサイトしか見つかりません。

私はハードウェアの構成の概要ではなく、現代のコンピュータの動作に活用されている電気関連の技術と、現代のコンピュータを構成する装置や部品がどんな素材でどのように作られているかなどの知識から身につけたいと考えています。

そこで、そのような知識を説明したWEBサイトをご存知の方はいらっしゃいませんか？

追記：質問を編集する以前は「私はハードウェアの構成の概要ではなく『物理学的なレベル』の知識から身につけたいと考えています。」と、「物理学的なレベル」という曖昧な言葉を使ってしまい、回答してくださった方を混乱、困惑させてしまったことをとても反省しております。同時に回答してくださった方に深く感謝いたします。
また、現在私が興味を示していることが、必ずソフトウェア開発に活かせるとは考えておりません。あくまで知りたいという思いがあるだけです！

Comment: 遠回りしすぎな気のせいがします。泳ぎ方を覚えるのにプールの作り方を知りたい、それもセメントの物理反応から入るような感じ。オイラにとって参考になった文献・サイトを紹介してもあなたの参考になるとは限らないし SO 向きの議題ではないかもしれないっス。 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1381/

Comment: 「物理学的なレベル」というのは具体的にどのレベルなのでしょう。フェルミなんとかのレベルですか？

Comment: 応用情報技術者試験などに挑戦されるのが良いと思います。おそらく、ソフトウェア開発にかかわる中で、いろんな知識が必要だと感じられたのだと思います。試験に臨むということで、成果に対する意欲もわいて、持続しやすいです。ハードウェアから理解したいのならば、ラズベリーパイなどの組み込みPCで、OSから実装するというのが手っ取り早いと思います。

Comment: [オペレーティングシステム開発](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/)参考までに

Comment: @WebSurfer さん、私は現代のコンピュータの動作に実際に使われている電気まわりの技術の知識と、コンピュータを構成する部品や装置がどんな素材からどんなふうに作られるのかというところに興味があります。

Comment: @TakahiroFunahashi  さん、やはり、中身をいじりにくい手持ちのPCのみでハードウェアの学習をしたいというのは少し大変かもしれませんね。是非、購入を検討してみます。ありがとうございます。

Comment: ここでのハードウェアとは「パソコンを構成する」ハードウェア、という事でしょうか？ / 「物理的」と「物理学的」では受ける印象が違うし、「どんな素材で」も少し範囲を広げ過ぎな印象です。学ぼうとする姿勢は大事ですが、質問にあたっては範囲を絞り込むことを心がけてください。

Answer (score 4):

# まだクローズ票もついていないので今のうち・・・

たぶんあなたは自分の興味がどこにあるのかまだ自分自身で把握していない状況なのだと思われます。あれもやってみたいこれも知りたい。でも何もかもを学ぶには人生の余白は狭すぎるのかもしれない・・・

おそらくジャンルが広すぎ内容が広すぎ深すぎで、これを専門にしていて生涯をかけている人が何人もいる中 Web サイトのブログ記事１個とか SO の質疑応答１個では分量的に断片的な話しかできないと予測されます。

数年（あるいは一生）を懸けて学ぶ内容なので大学に行くことをお勧めします。あなたが中高生なら電気・電子・物性系の学科のあるところに進学しましょう。既に社会人になっているなら通信教育（放送大学など）もアリでしょう。放送大学おすすめっス。地上波 TV をオイラがまだ持っていたときは流し聞きしているだけでも勉強になりました。（今は BS/ひかりTV しかやっていないんだっけ）

まあ半導体物性をやってもコンピュータソフトウエアの設計作成にはまず絶対役に立たないでしょうし、電気電子回路をやれば基板上回路の設計計算できるようになると思いますが製品設計の役には立ってもソフトウエア実装の役に立つかというと疑問っス。自分の興味対象や範囲を一度見つめなおしてみるといいでしょう。

---

持論ですが

- 勉強のための勉強は面白くないし続けられない
- 興味のあることはテキトーにネットサーフィン（死語）しているだけで目に留まるし、そのうち覚えてしまう
- 寝てる間などに脳内知識が整理されると突然「ああそういうことか」みたいに、一見無関係そうに見える事項が結びついて自分のものになる

ので<del>修行</del>勉強するぞ、みたいに意気込まずに適宜広く浅くいろんな本や web page を見てるだけでもいいんです。現代最新技術は専門家でも自分の専門分野の外は全貌を把握できないくらいに先鋭化しています。オイラたちユーザーとしては似て非なるものの長所短所の違いを知っているくらいで十分です。

- NOR FLASH と NAND FLASH の違いとか
- CMR と SMR の違いとか (HDD)
- `std::list` と `std::vector` と `std::deque` の違いとか ([c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b))

んで、理解が浅いことに物足りなさを感じたら、そこで初めて専門書なり通信教育なりを考えてみてもいいと思います（お値段も結構しますし）

Comment: 御回答ありがとうございます。  放送大学はBSかCS放送で見かけたことがあります。ぜひ見てみます。  「物理的学なレベル」という曖昧な言葉を用いたために、この質問者はいまいち何に興味があるのかわからないなぁ、という質問になってしまったことをお詫びいたします。   私が興味があるのは、現代のコンピュータの動作に活用されている電気関連の技術と、現代のコンピュータを構成する装置や部品がどんな素材でどのように作られているかということです。  また、現在私が興味を示している分野の知識を得てもソフトウェア開発に活きてこなくても構いません。とにかく「知りたい！」という思いなのです。

Answer (score 3):

774RRさんのコメント通りですが、あえて答えるなら、Webサイトでは断片的な記述と広告まみれであり、まともに語られていないことでしょう。仮に見つかったとしても内容に誤りがないとも限りません（稀有な存在ですと誤りは訂正されにくいです）。系統立てて理解するのであれば、書籍を購入することをお勧めします。

- コンピュータの構成と設計
  通称「パタへネ本」
- コンピュータアーキテクチャ 定量的アプローチ
  通称「ヘネパタ本」

Comment: ご回答感謝いたします。やはり、書籍は必須ですよね。安上がりに何でもしようと考えすぎになってしまいました。ぜひ、今すぐにでも購入を検討してみます。また「物理的なレベル」という非常に曖昧な言葉を用いてしまい、具体的に何に興味があるのかということを質問で伝えられず、非常に反省しております。  私が興味があるのは、現代のコンピュータの動作に活用されている電気関連の技術と、現代のコンピュータを構成する装置や部品がどんな素材でどのように作られているかということです。

Answer (score 2):

コンピューターを構成する要素の説明は比較的情報量が多めの分野で、わりと簡単に見つかります。
見つからない理由はそれぞれの基盤技術の名称等の基本的情報が得られていないせいかもしれません。

ひょっとすると単に検索キーワードがいまいちな場合もあります。
あたりまえですが、検索にもそれなりの技術が必要なのです。
例えば「ハードディスク」や「HDD」で検索しても販売サイトが優位にヒットし、その数は数億件になってしまいます。
この中から望む情報を得ることは困難でしょう。
でも、検索キーワードを「ハードディスク　原理」に変えるとヒットするのは数十万件になり販売サイトはリストされなくなります。
なおかつHDDの各部名称を示した図など、ちょっと技術寄りの情報があつまります。
この様にして知識を少しづつ増やしていってはどうでしょう。

自分たちは周りの限られた情報の中で生存することしかできませんが、その情報の質と量はある程度自分で選ぶことができます。
例えば「量子物理学」や「素粒子論」は物性の真に根源的原理ですが、一般的なビジネス用の「ソフトウエア開発」とは直接的には無関係です。
個人においてはこの世の全てのことを知ることはできないことは確定事項なので、必要のない情報はあきらめることも大事だと考えます。

Comment: 御回答ありがとうございます。原理という単語はよく私も使って検索していますし、初心者向けのWEBサイトのタイトルに使われがちなキーワードを除外したり、ac.jpを含めて検索したり、工夫をしているつもりではあるのですが、概要的な説明のWEBサイトが多く、なかなか物理学的なレベルからなものが見つかりません。やはり、書籍でないとそういうものは見つからないのかなぁ・・・と思ってSOに質問してみました。  また「物理学的なレベル」という曖昧な言葉を使って、突き詰めればきりがないとしか言いようがない質問をしてしまったことを非常に反省しております。実際に私が興味があるのは、現代のコンピュータの動作に活用されている電気関連の技術と、現代のコンピュータを構成する装置や部品がどんな素材でどのように作られているかということです。

Answer (score 2):

こちらをぜひ。かなり良著です。

[コンピュータシステムの理論と実装 (Amazon.co.jp)](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4873117127/)

OSを自作してみるというのも近道かもしれません。

[30日でできる! OS自作入門 (Amazon.co.jp)](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4839919844/)

というのは結局ソフトの話になってしまいますが、
ハードを動かす前になぜそのようなハードが必要か？が理解できると思います。

Comment: 回答に感謝いたします。ソフトウェアを理解することでハードウェアを理解するという考えは欠けていました。「まずはベースのハードウェアから理解しなければいけない」という思いが強くなりすぎているかもしれません。早速、購入を検討いたします。

Comment: ここで紹介された書籍はとても良いと思います。マイコンと呼ばれるMPUのマニュアルを読むこともお勧めします。ルネサスは旧日立系だけあって、マニュアルが丁寧です。私もSH3マイコンを扱うことで、覚えました。MPU（CPU）だけでは動作しないので、周りのメモリや水晶、バス、数多くあるMPUのPINがどんな役目を持っているのかや、ウォッチドッグとは何か、タイマ管理方法、RTCを保持するには電池が必要。OSとはそれらをどうしているのか、高級言語プログラムが動き出すまでに何が必要なのかなどなど。